# Select a textbox at the location where i have a match for the header data and data in first column

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

This is how my page looks like on which I need to work.

[image]

[The DOM looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDP2w.png)

Scenario :-  I need to traverse the table and where the header data(BH001 etc) and first column data(ABC etc) matches the data input by the user, I need to click on the textbox corresponding to it.

I have written the below specified code but its not working :-

```
public static void getMarksBox(WebDriver driver, String user, String taskCode) {
    UserData userNm = TestData.findUserById(user);
    String userName = userNm.getName();
    WebElement table = WaitUtils.waitForElement(driver, By.cssSelector("table.eds-o-table.cvr-c-table--marksbook"));
    List<WebElement> tableCols = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("td.eds-o-table__cell"));
    int columnIndex = -1;
    for(int i=1; i<tableCols.size();i++)
    {
        if(userName.equals(tableCols.get(i).findElement(By.cssSelector(".v-label-cvr-c-data-nav-link")).getText()))
        {
            columnIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    List<WebElement> tableRows = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr.eds-o-table__row"));
    List<WebElement> tableHeaders = tableRows.get(1).findElements(By.cssSelector(".v-label-cvr-u-margin-right--sm"));
    WebElement textBox = table.findElement(By.cssSelector(".v-textfield"));
    for(WebElement header :tableHeaders)
    {
        if(taskCode.equals(header.getText()))
        {
            textBox = tableRows.get(columnIndex);
            textBox.click();
            WaitUtils.sleepInSeconds(5);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add HTML code as text instead of image. And share your exact issue/error which you face instead of "code is not working".

Comment: I second Kamal.  I, personally am confused what you want here. What isn't working? Are you getting any error?

Comment: We can't see all your HTML, but I don't see any element with a class of `v-label-cvr-u-margin-right--sm`, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Problem Statement is : I need to select the textbox corresponding to a match 
 such as BH0001 & DEF. But I am unable to select that textbox.

Comment: @BhoomikaDatta check the xpath that I provide in my answer below. Let me know if that does't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this below xpath to access the inputbox directly, rather doing the loops that you have written in the above method.

```
//td[position()=count(//th[contains(.,'First Name')]/preceding-sibling::th)+1 and normalize-space(.)='ABC']/ancestor::tr//td[position()=count(//th[contains(.,'BH001')]/preceding-sibling::th)+1]//input[contains(@class,'v-textfield-eds-c-input')]
```

**Here is the general notation:**

```
//td[position()=count(//th[contains(.,'your reference column name')]/preceding-sibling::th)+1 and normalize-space(.)='reference value']/ancestor::tr//td[position()=count(//th[contains(.,'target column name')]/preceding-sibling::th)+1]//input[contains(@class,'v-textfield-eds-c-input')]
```

Answer (score 1):

As @supputuri suggested, you can find the matched row or cell directly via XPath/Css selector to avoid complex loop to reduce execution time.

```
public static void getMarksBox(WebDriver driver, String user, String taskCode) {

  UserData userNm = TestData.findUserById(user);
  String userName = userNm.getName();

  WebElement table = WaitUtils.waitForElement(driver, 
        By.cssSelector("table.eds-o-table.cvr-c-table--marksbook"));

  WebElement matchedRow = table.findElement(By.xpath(
        String.format("./tobdy/tr[td[1][normalize-space(.)='%s']]", userName)))

  WebElement matchedTextBox = matchedRow.findElement(
        By.cssSelector("./td:nth-child(2) input.v-textfield-eds-c-input"))

  matchedTextBox.click()

  // or you can directly find the matchedTextBox in one findElement
  String xpath = String.format(
       "./tobdy/tr[td[1][normalize-space(.)='%s']]" + 
       "/td[2]//input[contains(@class,'v-textfield-eds-c-input')]", userName)
  WebElement matchedTextBox = table.findElement(By.xpath(xpath))
  matchedTextBox.click()   
}
```